# VueJS and using fontawesome icons in CSS

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I have been using font awesome icon in mine vueJS ("vue": "~2.6.11") application component's CSS.

Could you please help me with following stuff.

```
th.sortable::after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f0dc";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    color: #999;
}
```

I have followed these steps to install font awesome in my Vue app.

```
yarn add @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome -D
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core -D
```

In main.js I have below code:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

but this does not work for me, If I directly give CDN URL (`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>")` of font awesome in index.html it works. I can see sorting icons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install font-awesome with npm/yarn

   ```sh
   > npm install font-awesome
   ```
2. On your main.js script, add

   ```js
   import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'
   ```
3. Use in component with:

   ```html
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.js, did you add this line after import :
`Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)`

Comment: Yes, I did, Please see main thread for the same

Comment: Indeed, this operation creates the global component `<font-awesome-icon />`

Comment: And here, you try to use FontAwesome in style section so like a stylesheet, that's why the CDN link works !

Comment: I did not get you ? Can you please elaborate what is missing here?